# Get value from input from the bootstrap-datepicker with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

In my Ruby-on-Rails project, I want to add a string from the bootstrap datepicker to a hidden field. I need to reference a input class, but I don't know how.

This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @dateevent]) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:date, @datelist) %>
    <%= f.input :date, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "placeholder" } %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is my implementation of the bootstrap datepicker:

```
    <input type="text" class='datepicker' >

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      multidate: true,
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
  });
</script>
```

I created a button, that adds the chosen dates to the hidden field:

```
<button class="btn3">Add dates to the hidden field</button>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click', ".btn3", function () {
        var datelist = $(".listb").text();
        document.getElementById('date').value = datelist;
      });
    });
</script>
```

To check, if the button really works, I did this:

```
<div class="listb">2016-2-2</div>
```

And when I press the button, 2016-2-2 is getting added to the hidden field, it is working.

Then I opened Firebug in Firefox and clicked on the field, where the bootstrap datepicker puts the chosen dates, it looks like this:

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text"></input>
```

In my Javascript code of the button, I tried these lines of code, but neither worked:

```
var datelist = $(".datepicker").text();
var datelist = $(".datepicker").val();
```

What do I need to type in, so the string of the field from bootstrap datepicker is added to datelist? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

This is the full page:

```
<h2>Neuer Event</h2><br>
<input type="text" class='datepicker' >

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      multidate: true,
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
  });
</script>
<br>
<div class="listb">2016-2-2</div>
<button class="btn3">Add dates to the hidden field</button>

<%= simple_form_for([@event, @dateevent]) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:date, @datelist) %>
    <%= f.input :date, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "placeholder" } %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).on('click', ".btn3", function () {
        var datelist = $(".listb").text();
        document.getElementById('date').value = datelist;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

//this [version](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html)

```
var datepicker = $('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {

       $('#date').val($(e.currentTarget).val());//1
       $('#date').val(datepicker.getDate());//2

    });
```

//or [bootstrap 3](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/)

```
var datepicker = $('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('dp.change', function(e) {

       e = {
    date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
    oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null

}


    });
```

Comment: This also works: `var datelist = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');`

Comment: How comes that `var datelist = $('.datepicker').datepicker('getDate');`breaks my date picker configuration? I see it clearly because I set the date picker to allow to select months only.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, this works:

```
var datelist = $("input.datepicker").val();
```